# In a function call, the number of Entrance logs are much lesser than the number of logs at the exit. Why is that?

Tags: java, c++, android, c, java-native-interface

The piece of function is like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL functionCall() {
     // Entrance
     printf("Time: %d\tFile: %s\tFunc: %s\tLine: %d\n", clock(), __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE);

    // other codes
    ...

    // Exit
    printf("Time: %d\tFile: %s\tFunc: %s\tLine: %d\n", clock(), __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE);
}
```

The total project is compiled to xxx.so file, called by java code at some Android app.
Now I am debugging the app, it will crash in the end. According to the logs, I find that the log number print at the entrance is only 14, but the log number print at the exit is more than 200.
How can this come out?

Comment: What "log number" are you talking about?  The 'Time'?

Comment: I think (s)he's asking about `__LINE__`.

Answer (score 1):

When printf format arguments don't line up correctly with the corresponding arguments, bad things happen in almost every implementation. For example, if given a 64-bit value where a 32-bit value is expected, Most implementations print the upper 32 bits from the 64-bit value. The next argument to print (in your case %s/**FILE**) will start out with the next 32-bits of the 64-bit value. In your example though, this data will get treated like a pointer to a string (aka a c string). Since the lower 32-bits of the value points at nothing, bad things can happen.

Here, printf might assume %d means 32-bit integer (its platform dependent). clock() returns "clock_t". It could be that clock_t is larger than 32 bits since it returns clock ticks. This would trigger the condition above.

**Best to avoid all this nonsense and use [std::cout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/).**

Comment: Thank you, but I think maybe this is not the point. I have watched the log, the unit of clock_t is second, which is unlikely to exceed 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

Also that method is a function that returns a value. If you have any return statements above the final logging line, it won't be executed of course. In C it can be quite difficult to arrange things so that final logging always happens. In C++ you just write a local class with a destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have caught all the normal return points, is there a possible exception condition?
Again, using a class with a destructor would trap help this.